Log de Queries para Rollback en transacciones correctas
Tengo varias bases de datos, y requiero un minucioso seguimiento de estas.
Descartando que ya los errores comunes se resuelven con los rollback automatizados en los comits.
Resulta que ahora hay posible errores “aceptables” por ejemplo:
Una salida de productos de una bodega relacionados a un despacho en un camión… que no debió de hacerse.
Algo como logear las queryes en mysql o estos eventos para hacer rollback manuales cuando las transacciones fueron correctas, pero no debieron hacerse por que alguien no vio un correo que cliente envio anulando el pedido.
Se me ocurre establecer un objeto Task y a partir de la trazabilidad del proceso almacenar todas las interacciones con la base de datos. Y hacer algo de ingeniería inversa en las queries que me permita desde un botón y un select box identificar el task y reversarlo.
Controlando también las etapas en la que se puede encontrar la trazabilidad del proceso.
Existe actualmente el laravel o synfony alguna opcion nativa del framework para lograr esto?

Eso no suena a un rollback en la db.. eso suena a un problema de negocios, que no deberia solucionarse con un rollback de db... eso hay que arreglarlo con un proceso de negocios.. porque eso no solo implica movimientos de db... deberia implicar reglas de negocios...

bueno para los ejecutivos la regla de negocios es: hiciste el proceso de despacho ... ahora debuelve todo lo que se hizo a su estado original ... entonces no se si hay algo en los ORM de laravel y/o Symfony que simplifique el trabajo de desarrollo ...

es que no se trata de eliminar datos... si no de ajustar saldos del stock ... entonces si hay un movimiento positivo, pense que los ORM de laravel/symfony tenian algo para generar un movimiento inverso como dices esto es sumas y restas...

¿Qué es un "rollback automatizado de un commit"? Es la primera vez que leo esa expresión... es algo propio de laravel?

los rollback de un comiit ocurren a nivel de la ejeucion de un conjunto de queries dentro de una transaccion, esto ocure en mysql si falla cualquier cosa ...  esa parte no tiene nada que ver con laravel ... el problema es cuando se quiere hacer lo mismo que un rollback pero de forma manual ... basandoce en un conjunto de queryes o transacciones que se ejecutaron sin error ...

ahora @jachguate no se si tu pregunta busca desviar la atencion de lo que se prentende en el post creo que con 30K de rep y mas de 8 años en el entorno... sabes a que se refieren los conceptos bien o mal nombrados ..

@Francisco, no pretendo desviar ninguna atención. Mi pregunta fue genuina y con el objeto de aprender. Llegué a esta pregunta por la etiqueta mysql, y en una base de datos relacional rollback y commit son dos operaciones, no solo distintas, sino que contrarias. Si haces un commit, se confirman los cambios en la transacción y si haces rollback se descartan, es decir, dentro de un commit no ocurrirá un rollback y dentro de un rollback no ocurrirá un commit. De hecho, en el lenguaje estándar ambas palabras son reservadas y tienen un comportamiento definido.

Como en base de datos lo que describes no tiene sentido, pensé que podría ser algo propio de las tecnologías reflejadas en las otras etiquetas y, siempre que puedo aprender algo nuevo, lo hago, sobre todo en StackOverflow.

por eso creo que la pregunta es clara al final Existe actualmente el laravel o synfony alguna opcion nativa del framework para lograr esto?

@FranciscoNuñezIALover, a ver si entendí. Vos estas buscando una implementación o herramienta nativa que para cada operación realizada entre un START TRANSACTION y un COMMIT genere las consultas (querys) inversas para poder volver para atrás dichas operaciones cuando fuera necesario. correcto?

Para tu caso en particular debes anular los pedidos. Mediante la anulación de los pedidos debes crear la lógica necesaria que te permita volver todo  "a la normalidad". Por ejemplo, si se cancela un pedido todas las unidades de los artículos vuelven al stock del inventario.
Entiendo que no es necesario hacer uso de las TRANSACTIONS. Por una buena regla de lógica de negocios no debería.

@Marcos si y no, no necesito que sea lo inverso ... con tal de tener los queryes que ese proceso ejecuto ... alamacenados yo podria crear la herramienta que haga lo inverso ...

@mechavarria ese es el problema como crear la logica de la anulacion de un proceso cuando se desconoce todo lo que eso toco en el camino... pro eso mi interes en busca de algo que me permita almacenar por tarea, que fue lo que se hizo... algo como un log de queries... por eso preguntava a los desarrolladores de symfony y laravel si hay algo para loggear los queries en nativamente en los framework de php ...

@FranciscoNuñezIALover, dentro de la transacción hay un UPDATE o un DELETE te diría que crear la consulta inversa después de completada la transacción va a ser muy difícil, ya que no tendrías guardados los valores anteriores.

@Marcos gracias a todos por los comentarios, pero si hay solucion usando los logger de cada framework... no necesito hacer update Delete en este punto.

Ok, en lo que he logrado investigar, nativamente cada framework tiene un sistema de log o logger que puede ser implementando para registrar lo que va sucediendo en cada pedido a lo largo del proceso.
Como la idea es tomar un proceso y menciono que se puede identificar con un ID de tarea, la idea quedaria plasmada de la siguiente forma:
Symfony Logger de queries a un archivo JSON por Tarea:

Definimos un servicio de logging personalizado que registre las consultas SQL en archivos JSON:

// config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Service\DatabaseLogger:
        tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'kernel.request', method: 'onKernelRequest' }


Creamos la clase DatabaseLogger que registrará las consultas SQL:

// src/Service/DatabaseLogger.php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

class DatabaseLogger
{
    private $logDir;

    public function __construct(string $logDir)
    {
        $this->logDir = $logDir;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $pedidoId = $request->query->get('pedido_id');

        // Aqui debemos implementar la lógica para registrar las consultas SQL en un archivo JSON
        $jsonLog = json_encode($event->getRequest()->attributes->all());

        // Guarda el JSON en un archivo
        file_put_contents($this->logDir.'/query_log_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.json', $jsonLog, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}


Configuramos el directorio de logs en tu archivo de configuración:

// config/packages/parameters.yaml
parameters:
    log_dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/log/task'

Laravel Logger de queries a un archivo JSON por Tarea:

Registramos un listener para el evento DB::listen en el archivo AppServiceProvider:

// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $pedidoId = request()->query('pedido_id');
        // Listener para el evento DB::listen
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
            $jsonLog = json_encode($query->sql);
            // Guarda el JSON en un archivo
            $logFileName = 'pedido_' . $pedidoId . '_query.log';
            Log::channel('query')->useFiles(storage_path('logs/' . $logFileName))->info($jsonLog);
        });
    }
}


Configura el canal de logging en el archivo config/logging.php:

'channels' => [
    'query' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/query.log'),
        'level' => 'info',
    ],
    // Otros canales de logging...
],

Segun la documentacion, cuando utilicemos useFiles en nuestro código para especificar el nombre del archivo de log dinámicamente, este valor se ignorará y se utilizará el que proporcionemos en el código.
Nota: Esta propuesta no la he podido aun comprobar, estoy en proceso de desarrollo he implementacion, si todo va bien tendre en un archivo por Pedido lo que toco en la base de datos, de requerir anular un pedido, podre hacer la trasabilidad de todo lo que ese pedido modifico en la base de datos.
Nota 2: Esta respuesta comprende los dos framework, planteo liberar esto como un modulo/pluggin que pueda ser implementado en cualquier escenario en la que se necesite.
